# Reference from multiple mongoose schemas using .populate()

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

```
const blogPostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  postedBy: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    ref: 'Employer',
},  

});

  BlogPost.findById(id)
    .populate("postedBy", "_id fName lName")
    .exec();
```

I have three schemas User, Employer & blogPost

I'm trying to  `.populate("postedBy", "_id fName lName")` from either the User model or Employer depending on who posted the blog.

How would I reference from two schemas is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can chain multiple .populate() in the same find()

```
BlogPost.findOne().populate().populate().populate().exec((err, post) => {
        if (err) { console.error(err);
                   return res.status(500).json({ error: err }) }
        res.json(post);
    })
```

});